# Uncaught ReferenceError: module/require is not defined

Tags: node.js

I am learning about how to `create/import/export` modules in `Node.js`, 
i have gone through [these](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) and was trying to learn by creating a sample application.
I issued the `command` from the root folder (Poc1) `"npm install requirejs"`, and included the file `require.js` in the `Start.html`.

When i open `Start.html` in browser i get -

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined", "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined".

I am not sure what mistake i am making or what other files i need to include to get it working ?

For sample application below is folder structure

```
Poc1 folder has these files and folders (greetings.js, main.js, Start.html, node_modules)
Poc1\node_modules has (requirejs\require.js)
```

grreetings.js is defined as below

```
    module.exports.sayHelloInEnglish = function(){
        return "Hello";
    }

    module.exports.sayHelloInSpanish = function(){
        return "Hola";
    }
```

main.js is defined as below

```
    var greetings = require("./greetings.js");
    function someFunc(){
        var g1 = greetings.sayHelloInEnglish();
        var g2 = greetings.sayHelloInSpanish();

        alert(g1);
        alert(g2);
    }
```

Start.html is defined as below

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="greetings.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules\requirejs\require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span>Below is button</span>
  <input type="button" onclick="someFunc()" value="clickMe"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think those exports aren't correct:

```
exports.sayHelloInEnglish = function(){
    return "Hello";
}

exports.sayHelloInSpanish = function(){
    return "Hola";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed the path as suggested and now getting below errors:
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined.  
Uncaught Error: Module name "greetings.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Comment: @SunilThakur In your HTML file, try put the `<script type="text/javascript" src="greetings.js"></script>`   before the `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>` and see if it solves it.

Comment: Tried that still the same issue.  I tried even creating a node.js package for my module (greetings.js) by using "npm init" command and then specified the new module as a dependency in root.package.json file, however when i run "rootFolder> npm install", npm is unable to find the dependent package (the one which i have created) as it is expecting it there in npm registry, whereas i have not published it yet. I am looking into it.